# Inheritance in Static Methods

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

Why does the below code print "Main"?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Main");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new SubMain();
        m.method();
    }
}

class SubMain extends Main
{
    public static void method()
    {
        System.out.println("SubMain");
    }
}
```

At runtime, `m` is pointing to an instance of `Submain`, so it should conceptually print "SubMain".

Comment: You can even write `Main m = null;` and then call the method, the expression before the dot is not used at all.

Comment: What if we didn't overridden method in sub class "Submain" and use 
SubMain m = new SubMain(); 
m.method();

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Static methods are resolved on the compile-time type of the variable. `m` is of type `Main`, so the method in `Main` is called.

If you change it to `SubMain m ...`, then the method on `SubMain` will be called.

Comment: In addition to this answer, I recommend you do not call static methods from an instance object and call them from the class name (ex: SubMain.method() rather than m.method()).

Comment: This is why java warns you when you try to invoke a static method on an instance object.

Comment: @EricFitting Java doesn't warn you but your ide may warn you.

Answer (score 15):

It is because static methods are not polymorphic. Moreover static method should be invoked not by object but using the class, i.e. `Main.method()` or `SubMain.method()`.
When you are calling `m.method()` java actually calls `Main.method()` because m is of type Main.

If you want to enjoy polymorphism do not use static methods.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse gives me this sort of warning when I try to do this sort of thing:

> The static method XXX() from the type XXX should be accessed in a static way

Static methods do not take part in inheritance. The variable is of type `Main`, so the compiler resolved your function call to `Main.method()`.

For added fun, try setting `m` to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Java performs early binding for static methods, unlike instance methods which are dynamically bound.

Because your object variable is of type Main the call is bound to the superclass implementation at compile time.

A good explanation is available [here](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

static methods are statically binded with their class name because m is type of Main class
then after compilation it would look like as following
Main.method();
after compilation of your class 
run the following command 
javap -c Main
u can see the jvm assembly code for Main class
 and u would see following
m.method  //invoke static
invoke static ,invoke special tells that static binding
invoke special,invoke interface tells that dynamic binding