# Java inheritance and subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

Java noob here with a quick question.

This is the basic layout of a class I will be using.

```
public class Foo{
    public static void Method1(){
        Method 2();
    }
    public static void Method2(){
    }
}
```

And here is a subclass.

```
public class Foo2{
    public static void Method2(){
    }
}
```

How can I write this so that calling `Foo2.Method1()` uses `Foo2.Method2()` instead of `Foo1.Method2()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance in Static Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987127/inheritance-in-static-methods)

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to create a `Method1` in `Foo2` as well, which will call `Foo2.Method2`. `Foo.Method2` being static is always going to be called by `Foo.Method1`, regardless of further subclassing. There's just no overriding when it comes to static methods.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods are not polymorphic, so there is no dynamic dispatch. Hence the solution is

- to make `Method2` non-static to activate dynamic dispatch or
- to <strike>override</strike>hide `Method1` in `Foo2` or
- if that would cause a lot of code duplication, to create a helper method for <strike>overriding</strike>hiding only parts of the code.

---

Details about static methods: these are methods on the class level, hence

- you cannot override them - if you define them in `Foo2` as well, you are hiding the implementation in `Foo`.
- you should not call them on an instance, as you are doing in `Method1`. If you ccall them in the conventional way, `Foo.Method2`, it becomes obvious what the problem and the possible solutions are.

Comment: +1 for at least hinting why this question doesn't make any sense ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance and method overloading / overwriting only work on the non-static part of a class. Therefore there is no way to do what you want. This is also the reason why `static` should be used as few as possible - it cannot be extended.