# Can I get the child class name in Java

Tags: java

Dog.java

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
.....

}
```

---

Animal.java

```
public class Animal {

   public static  String getName() {

       String callerClassName = ????; //How to get the class Dog, when I call from TestCase
       return "Animal";
   }
}
```

when I use TestCase class to Dog.getName(), how to get the className Dog instead of Animal when I use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()

```
public class TestCase {
   public static  String getName(){

      return Dog.getName();
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that your method `getName()` is static, and thus not subject to inheritance (loosely speaking - not sure exactly what the JLS says about this, might look it up ...)

Comment: Perhaps if you explain better what you're trying to achieve, you will get a good answer. So far, the only thing I can suggest is to just have a static getName() method in your Dog class that just returns "Dog".

Comment: @henry: huh? Please explain what you just posted.

Comment: See also: [SO: Inheritance in Static Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4987149/1212960).

Answer (score 3):

> **Can I get the child class name in Java**

Not the way you're doing it ...

Your method is static, and is not subject to inheritance.  Static methods of the same name defined in a subclass can *hide* the superclass method, but they do not override them.  A hidden static method can always be referenced by it's fully qualified name (i.e. `Animal.getName()`).

When you invoke `Dog.getName()`, the compiler is merely resolving `Animal.getName()` for you.

See also: [SO: Inheritance in Static Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987149/1212960).

---

From a different angle:

> **Can I get the child class name in Java**

Assuming your method is changed to be non-static, see [Wyzard's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11571625/1212960).

Answer (score 3):

For a non-static method, you could use `this.getClass()` to get the concrete class of the object it's called on, but that isn't applicable to a static method.  When you call an inherited static method like that, the subclass isn't involved at all, so I don't think that information is available.

This may be a sign of a design problem anyway, though.  Because there's no dynamic dispatch for static methods, to call `getName()` on the `Dog` class you have to refer to `Dog` explicitly in your source code.  There's not much point having a method that returns the name of a subclass when you have to know the subclass *already* in order to call the method on it.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you provide a static `getName` method in your `Dog` class this is not possible. Even though you make a call to `Dog.getName()` the static method of `Animal` is invoked, where it is declared after all, and not of `Dog`, hence the caller class *is* `Animal` and not `Dog`.

If you want to solve this, it depends on what you want to achieve, you could:

1. Declare a static `getName` method in your `Dog` class.
2. Make the methods non-static and put the whole problem to inheritance, where the methods will show different behavior. Instead of hiding, inheritance will be applied.

You should take a look at  [Overriding and Hiding Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html), it might help.